# setFilter on TextButtons libgdx

Tags: java, libgdx

```
private void Button()
{
    Skin buttonSkin = new Skin();

    buttonSkin.addRegions(interface); 
    TextButtonStyle style = new TextButtonStyle();
    style.up = buttonSkin.getDrawable("button");

    style.down = buttonSkin.getDrawable("button_pressed");

    final TextButton button = new TextButton("", style); 
    button.setColor(Color.GREEN);
}
```

How can I add a filter because the image button is shelled?

Can I use setFilter?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should rather use [ImageButton](https://libgdx.badlogicgames.com/nightlies/docs/api/com/badlogic/gdx/scenes/scene2d/ui/ImageButton.html) or [ImageTextButton](https://libgdx.badlogicgames.com/nightlies/docs/api/com/badlogic/gdx/scenes/scene2d/ui/ImageTextButton.html) classes with their

```
    public Image getImage()
```

method.

In classic Button/Textbutton you should be able to achieve it by

```
    TextButton textButton = null;

    //...

    ( (Texture) textButton.getStyle().down ).setFilter(TextureFilter.Nearest, TextureFilter.Nearest);
    //there are also: up, disabled, check, checkedOver, over Drawables
```

but to be honest it is not looking very proper. If you are using TexturePacker to pack atlas for your skin (assuming you are using skins) you can also pack it with Linear (for example) filter and it should be handled.